# React-Native init project fail to run

Tags: react-native

Got an issue after react-native upgrade and now version is 0.2.0

I got bunch of errors from 
`react-native init HelloWorld`

Error log

```
make: *** [Release/validation.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.9.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/jyao/Desktop/HelloWorld/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a library.
`ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5`

Make sure you installed everything including the Xcode CLI.
If you do, restart your package manager.